# Codeigniter MYSQL Returning Most Recent Row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following code below, and I am not sure of the best way to modify it so that it shows the last entered row into the database.

The `user_date` column is displayed like this: `2010-05-06 12:37:28`

**Controller:**

```
$result = $this->shared_model->GetJustJoinedUser();
    $data['just_joined_user'] = $result->row_array();
```

**Model:**

```
function GetJustJoinedUser()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *
                              FROM {$this->_table['users']} user
                              WHERE user_description != '' AND user_image != '' AND (user_twitter != '' OR user_youtube != '' OR user_vimeo!= '')
                              ORDER BY user_date DESC
                              LIMIT 1");

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `$this->db->last_query()` ?

Comment: @PawCabelin Yes and for some reason it is causing me to get a 500 error

Comment: try my answer maybe it could help

Comment: Your query looks okay, but you're returning the query object itself. If you want to return the row's data, use `return $query->row()` or a similar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query already get the last inserted row but with some restriction in the WHERE statement.

If you want the real last row, just strip the WHERE statement like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM {$this->_table['users']} user ORDER BY user_date DESC LIMIT 1");
```

you do not seem to know much about the SQL queries, so i suggest you read some tuto about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could fix your problem but you could try something like this.

`$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();`

then use this `$last_id` to query your last inserted user. I hope this helps

`$this->db->insert_id()` 
**Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).**

**UPDATE**

```
$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();

$this->db->where('id', $last_id);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
if($query)
{
    $query = $query->result_array();
    //$query here contains the details of the last inserted user
}
```

Im just showing the idea on how to get the last user inserted. I hope that would help you

Comment: Could you do a full example for me to try as its still dying

Comment: @JessMcKenzie can you tell me what you really want to do here? you just want to display the last inserted row?

Comment: Correct the code that I am trying to fix should show the last user joined = that last user entered into the db